# How to use getPackageManager?

Tags: android, package-managers

In order to show installed applications on the Android emulator, I tried this code. It compiles successfully but doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
package pack.GetAllInstalledApplications;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class GetAllInstalledApplicationsExample extends Activity {

 public  ArrayList <PackageInfoStruct> res = new ArrayList <PackageInfoStruct>();

 public ListView list;
 public String app_labels[];


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getPackages();

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        try{
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>         (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,app_labels));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Err ++> " + e.getMessage());
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

 }
private ArrayList
 <PackageInfoStruct> getPackages() {
    ArrayList
 <PackageInfoStruct> apps = getInstalledApps(false);
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i < max; i++) {
        apps.get(i);
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList
  <PackageInfoStruct> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {

    List
  <PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    try{
        app_labels = new String[packs.size()];
    }catch(Exception e){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    for(int i=0;i < packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PackageInfoStruct newInfo = new PackageInfoStruct();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);

        app_labels[i] = newInfo.appname;
    }
    return res;
}
    }  
  class PackageInfoStruct {             
 String appname = "";           
 String pname = "";             
 String versionName = "";      
 int versionCode = 0;           
 Drawable icon;                 
  }
```

Comment: You have to give us a little more info as to how it doesn't work. Does it just not display the packages? Does it crash? If so can you post the error log?

Comment: it was compiled correctly , but I did not find the app icon

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `list.setAdapter` you should probably use a different layout. I tried `simple_list_item_1`

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, app_labels));
```

and it appears to then display the items correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering the app labels you should add some log in order to understand if you are actually retrieving the apps. Verified that then you can deal with the adapter.

Remember that the ArrayAdapter's constructor get as second parameter the resource id of a text view (otherwise it crashes), so make sure of that.

Moreover, for discarding the system package I use this line of code:

...
if ((pi.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) continue;
...

where pi is the PackageInfo.

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I change the adapter layout, use the **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**  on your code, and it works.